# Extracting numbers from a column "attached" to characters

Tags: r

I have data in the form,

```
+PRODUCT NAME 6CT 144cl
+NEW PRODUCT NAME 72cl
```

Which has characters, spaces and numbers. I am only interested in the number `144` and `72` for example, however when I use `grep` and extract just the numbers I also extract the number `6` from the first row.

How can I just extract the `144cl` and `72cl` (or all numbers "attached" to the `cl` string? i.e. there is no white space between `144` and `cl`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stringr` and a positive lookahead:

```
stringr::str_extract("+PRODUCT NAME 6CT 144cl", "\\d+(?=cl)")
# [1] "144"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string<-"+PRODUCT NAME 6CT 144cl"
gsub('.* (\\d+).*$','\\1',string)
[1] "144"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable to have a look ahead to determine whether the next characters are indeed `cl`.

Capturing all including the `cl` part:

```
x="+PRODUCT NAME 6CT 144cl" "+NEW PRODUCT NAME 72cl" 
sub('.*\\s((\\d+)(?>cl)).*','\\1',x,perl = T)
[1] "144cl" "72cl"
```

If there are more than one value with cl in the same line then you will have to use `gsub` instead of `sub`.

If you don't need the `cl` part but only the numbers then the capturing parenthesis should not be included:

```
sub('.*\\s(\\d+)(?>cl).*','\\1',x,perl = T)
[1] "144" "72"
```